# How do you get the gel canister?

Tags: bastion

How do you get the gel canister skill in bastion?

I'm not sure how you are supposed to summon the turret, which is what I've read before.

Answer (score 6):

You get the memento after starting a "New Game+." It's in the Arsenal, under the Skills menu.

You can summon the sentry turret pet after [speaking to Zia](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRFez-ikQYs).

Comment: Doesn't work. Does this only work on the steam version or something?

Comment: Look in your Arsenal, under Skills.

Answer (score 2):

From watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-c26R80OmQ&feature=related) it looks like it'll just show up in your arsenal. After you see it there, you can ask Zia about it and it'll show up as a pet in the Bastion.